# Linear algebra unitary operator problem

Tags: linear-algebra, unitary-matrices

I am not undertanding what I have to do in letter (c) of this problem.. I just wrote $\alpha_1=\begin{bmatrix} \cos\phi & -\sin\phi\\ \sin\phi & \cos\phi \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}1\\0\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}\cos\phi \\ \sin\phi\end{bmatrix}$

and $\alpha_2=\begin{bmatrix} \cos\phi & -\sin\phi\\ 
\sin\phi & \cos\phi \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}0\\1\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}-\sin\phi \\ \cos\phi\end{bmatrix}$

[image: Hoffman, Linear Algebra - page 309]

Comment: It is an exercise of hoffman's linear algebra book at page 309 chapter 8.4 of unitary operators

Comment: Thanks for your efforts to format the matrices; matrices get tricky for those learning mathjax.  In my edit I merely inserted backslashes immediately preceding the trig functions. E.g. `\cos \phi, \sin \phi`.

Answer (score 1):

Let $e_1 , e_2$ be standart basis vectors for $R^2$

$\epsilon_1=n_1e_1+n_2e_2$ ,$\epsilon_2=m_1e_1+m_2e_2$

$U_\phi(e_1)=\begin{pmatrix} \cos\phi \\ \sin\phi\end{pmatrix}$ , $U_\phi(e_2)=\begin{pmatrix} -\sin\phi \\ \cos\phi \end{pmatrix}$

Let $v=c_1\alpha_1+c_2\alpha_2$ then

$U_\theta(v)=U_\theta c_1\alpha_1+U_\theta c_2\alpha_2$

$=c_1U_\theta\alpha_1+c_2U_\theta\alpha_2=c_1U_\theta U_\phi\epsilon_1+c_2U_\theta U_\phi\epsilon_2$$=U_\theta U_\phi(c_1\epsilon_1+c_2\epsilon_2)$

$=U_\theta U_\phi(c_1n_1e_1+c_1n_2e_2+c_2m_1e_1+c_2m_2e_2)=(c_1n_1+c_2m_1)U_\theta U_\phi e_1+(c_1n_2+c_2m_2)U_\theta U_\phi e_2$

$=(c_1n_1+c_2m_1)\begin{pmatrix} \cos\phi+\theta \\ \sin\phi+\theta\end{pmatrix}+(c_1n_2+c_2m_2)\begin{pmatrix} -\sin\phi+\theta \\ \cos\phi+\theta \end{pmatrix}$

$\begin{pmatrix}  (c_1n_1+c_2m_1)\\ (c_1n_2+c_2m_2) \end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix} n_1 & m_1 \\ n_1 & m_2\end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} c_1 \\ c_2\end{pmatrix}$

so we can say that

$(c_1n_1+c_2m_1)\begin{pmatrix} \cos\phi+\theta \\ \sin\phi+\theta\end{pmatrix}+(c_1n_2+c_2m_2)\begin{pmatrix} -\sin\phi+\theta \\ \cos\phi+\theta \end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix} \cos\phi+\theta & -\sin\theta+\phi \\ \sin \phi+\theta & \cos \phi + \theta  \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} n_1 & m_1 \\ n_1 & m_2\end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} c_1 \\ c_2\end{pmatrix}$

so our matrix is $\begin{pmatrix} \cos\phi+\theta & -\sin\theta+\phi \\ \sin \phi+\theta & \cos \phi + \theta  \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} n_1 & m_1 \\ n_1 & m_2\end{pmatrix} $